# Allow move but not put in internal-sftp

Tags: files, sftp, privileges, account-restrictions

is it possible with the internal-sftp to allow mv command from dir A to B but not allow put to A?

Comment: What Unix variant is the server running? I'm pretty sure you can't do that with OpenSSH's internal-sftp, but you could do it by replacing it by a custom implementation, or perhaps with a security framework such as SELinux.

Comment: SELinux is not an option. So I guess this leaves me with custom build